# Multiple same name group definitions or if system

Tags: python, regex

my first time here, title is bad i know :)

Well, this is what i'm trying to do

Input possibility 1: `SOMETHING BLAH  always same words here (here comes date/time text, called group 1) [group 2 text]: (group 3 text) END`

Input 2: `SOMETHING BLAH  [group 2 text] always same words here (here comes date/time text, called group 1): (group 3 text) END`

group2 can appear before or after

Now, using python and module re, is it possible to match either of these inputs using only 1 regex?

Example (Obviously, something like this is not possible as it contains same name groups):

```
"SOMETHING BLAH (always same words here \((?P<group1>.{1,40})\) \[(?P<group2>.*?)\]: \((?P<group3>.*?)\)|\[(?P<group2>.*?)\] always same words here \((?P<group1>.{1,40})\): (group 3 text) ) END", re.DOTALL
```

It's just an exmp for what im trying to do

Comment: If the title is bad, consider fixing it.  This is just about regex group names.  Consider changing your title to reflect what's actually in your actual question.

Comment: Why is it ‘obviously not possible’? That would be a really dumb restriction if it were true. You do that sort of thing in Perl all the time; in fact, your pattern compiles just fine in Perl with that exact syntax. Have you looked at Matthew Barnett’s `regex` module for Python? I believe it has a branch reset operation which would help you here.

Comment: not possible in python, some other langs yes, like .NET as i heard, and Perl as you say. Terrible thing at the moment, don't know if something like this is possible in Python 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you use optional groups:

```
>>> patt = re.compile("foo (?P<name>[0-9]+)?")
>>> patt.search("blah foo 999 bar").groupdict()
{'name': '999'}
>>> patt.search("blah foo bar").groupdict()
{'name': None}
```

Your example, somewhat simplified for length:

```
prefix (?P<optional1>\[.*?\])? same-words \((?P<date>.*?)\)(?P<optional2> \[.*?\])?: \((?P<g3>.*?)\) END
```

Then once you have a match, you can do:

```
d = patt.search(str).groupdict()
g2 = d["optional1"] if d["optional1"] is not None else d["optional2"]
```

Comment: sorry for delay, thanks for this solution, i don't like using one more test but it appears there is no other way at the moment so i'm going with this one. Thanks